# Unable to compare two equal strings in Perl

Tags: regex, perl

I have two strings:

```
$string_1 = "Neben den Schlichtungsgesetzen der Länder gibt es für den Fall einer möglichen Verletzung von Verbraucherschutzbestimmungen die Möglichkeit, besondere Schlichtungsstellen nach dem UKlaG anzurufen. Das Verfahren wird in § 14 Abs. 2 UKlaG konkretisiert und schreibt u. a. vor die Unabhängigkeit bzw. Unparteilichkeit der Schlichtungsstelle, die Zugänglichkeit ihrer Verfahrensregeln und das rechtliche Gehör für die Beteiligten, d. h. die Möglichkeit der Parteien, Tatsachen und Bewertungen vorzubringen. Dabei ist das Schlichtungsverfahren auf die Verwirklichung des Rechts ausgerichtet mit der Folge, dass dem beschwerten Verbraucher gem. §§ 1 und 2 UKlaG ein Anspruch auf Unterlassung und Widerruf zusteht. Anspruchsberechtigt sind die in § 3 UKlaG näher beschriebenen anspruchsberechtigten Stellen, wozu auch qualifizierte Einrichtungen nach § 4 UKlaG und rechtsfähige Berufsverbände, die IHK oder HWK gehören. Prüfungsgegenstand und -umfang sind folglich potenzielle rechtliche Ansprüche und nicht in erster Linie die Interessen der Parteien, wie es in der Mediation der Fall ist.";

$string_2 = "Neben den Schlichtungsgesetzen der Länder gibt es für den Fall einer möglichen Verletzung von Verbraucherschutzbestimmungen die Möglichkeit, besondere Schlichtungsstellen nach dem UklaG anzurufen. Das Verfahren wird in § 14 Abs. 2 UKlaG konkretisiert und schreibt u. a. vor die Unabhängigkeit bzw. Unparteilichkeit der Schlichtungsstelle, die Zugänglichkeit ihrer Verfahrensregeln und das rechtliche Gehör für die Beteiligten, d. h. die Möglichkeit der Parteien, Tatsachen und Bewertungen vorzubringen. Dabei ist das Schlichtungsverfahren auf die Verwirklichung des Rechts ausgerichtet mit der Folge, dass dem beschwerten Verbraucher gem. §§ 1 und 2 UKlaG ein Anspruch auf Unterlassung und Widerruf zusteht. Anspruchsberechtigt sind die in § 3 UKlaG näher beschriebenen anspruchsberechtigten Stellen, wozu auch qualifizierte Einrichtungen nach § 4 UKlaG und rechtsfähige Berufsverbände, die IHK oder HWK gehören. Prüfungsgegenstand und -umfang sind folglich potenzielle rechtliche Ansprüche und nicht in erster Linie die Interessen der Parteien, wie es in der Mediation der Fall ist.";
```

When I compare this I can not get pass through.

**I tried :**

```
if ($string_1 eq $string_2) {
    code to run after pass through; 
}
```

I can not pass though inside `if`. Kindly anyone suggest any idea to overcome this

Thank you!

Comment: You could resolve this with basic debugging techniques. Split the strings into smaller chunks until they *do* pass 'eq', then add in the rest of the string until they fail

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have ***1*** different capitalization of a letter.

```
UKlaG vs UklaG
 ^        ^
```

Consider using case-insensitive comparison or correcting the capitalization mistake.

Case-insensitive comparison:

```
if (lc $string_1 eq lc $string_2) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks sshashank!, so how can I compare without case sensitive? please share any idea if you have

Comment: Note that `lc $string1 eq lc $string2` can [act incorrectly for strings containing some non-latin characters](http://www.effectiveperlprogramming.com/2012/02/fold-cases-properly/). You'll get better results using a case-insensitive regexp match like `$string1 =~ /\A\Q$string2\E\z/i`. If you're on Perl 5.16 then you can enable the `fc` feature and check `fc $string1 eq fc $string2`.